# Import could not be resolved with custom library in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, module, visual-studio-code

I have created a `myutils.py` file, added it to `PYTHONPATH` via `.bashrc`, and it correctly gets imported during the actual runtime.

However, when I'm viewing the file that imports the library in Visual Studio Code, it doesn't recognize it and gives me the warning `Import "myutils" could not be resolved PylancereportMissingImports`.

How do I show Visual Studio Code that I'd like it to cache the contents of my custom module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing the interpreter might help solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: It starts working if I use Python 3.9.5, though i'd like to use it with 3.10 (in which my custom folder shows up in sys.path). Is that not yet supported in 3.10?

Comment: Maybe. 3.10 is new, so vscode may not support it yet.

Answer (score 1):

In `settings.json` file you have to add the paths from which folder you import `myutils`:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "<path to the folder that contains myutils.py>",
]
```